# Can we add the destination query parameter to a link from yml configuration?

Tags: navigation, 8

When creating a link from yaml

ie: mymodule.links.action.yml

```
my_module.my_entity.add:
  route_name: node.add
  title: 'Add My Entity'
  route_parameters:
        node_type: 'my_entity'
  appears_on:
    - my_module.my_entity.admin_content
```

Is there a way that this links would be generated with the **?destination=path/to/redirect** ?

Comment: You can try creating a custom route for that link. And add the destination in the route definition.

Comment: @eyal Can you be more specific about `adding the destination in the route definition`? Should the custom route be done by code using route callback ? Thanks

Comment: Try and create a mymodule.routing.yml file. In that for you can define new routes and provide parameters for them. I'm not sure if it is possible to add a destination parameter but it is worth the try.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you can add the destination query directly in the yml file. 
@see : \Drupal\Core\Menu\LocalActionDefault::getOptions

ie: mymodule.links.action.yml

```
my_module.my_entity.add:
  route_name: node.add
  title: 'Add My Entity'
  route_parameters:
        node_type: 'my_entity'
  options:
    query:
      destination: '/path/to/redirect'
  appears_on:
    - my_module.my_entity.admin_content
```

Answer (score 13):

The query string is not part of the route. The controller fetches the query parameters from the webserver request and does the processing, in this case returns a redirect:

```
$request = \Drupal::request();
$destination = $request->query->get('destination');
return new RedirectResponse($destination);
```

When generating an url for the example mentioned in the question, the `node_type` is a parameter that goes into the route as configured in the routing yml file and the destination is a query parameter that is appended to the url and is not part of the route:

```
$url = \Drupal\Core\Url::fromRoute(
    'node.add',
     array('node_type' => $type->id()),
     array(
       'query' => array('destination' => $destination),
       'absolute' => TRUE,
     )
);
```

On both sides the routing system ignores whatever you put in the query of the url, you have to handle this in the code yourself.